# how to keep local default gateway when connecting witn VPN

Tags: vpn, gateway

i used VPN to connect to my Windows server 2016 at our office.

vpn pptp and Remina. everything works very well.

but when i disconnect, the default gateway is changes and do not come back to local one. This can be prevented on Windows machine by disabling on TCP/IP properties to change the default gateway.

is there an equivalent on Ubuntu VPN. i have tried settings for Routes or Use this connection only for resources... but without success.